# Can I use fread to download all the files in a folder?

Tags: r, datatable, fread

I have a folder with thirty files, each about 0.5GB.

I'd like to read them all into a single data table. Ideally, I'd like to also read in only the files that have a particular word.

I'm using data table, so I'd like to use `fread` if possible. I tried putting the folder into the path argument that didn't work.

I'm trying this approach, and I'm wondering if there's a better one

```
folder <- "~/Downloads/My Folder"
all.files <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = ".csv")
setwd(folder)

l <- lapply(all.files, fread, sep=",")
dt <- rbindlist( l )
setkey( dt , ID )
```

These are examples of the filenames

```
filename01_2020.csv
filename01_2019.csv
filename01_2018.csv
```

Comment: Is it the file name with a word or the value in one of the columns.  If it is the former, `files <- list.files(pattern = 'yourpattern_.*\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: All the files have the same structure and a similar naming pattern (but not exactly the same name). It's like: `nameOfFile_DateTime.csv`

Comment: The DateTime is literally that string or the actual date and time

Comment: Can you please mention what kind of transformations you needed in those files. That would help in suggesting better solutions given that the data would be big when reading lot of files

Comment: I'd like to put them into a single data table, unique the data table and then analyze the data, like looking at it on a time series basis and aggregating it

Comment: Btw, do you have articles that you recommend on working with references in data tables? I'd like to make my DT unique without copying the object

Comment: Do you want to get the `dt` unique by a single column or the whole dataset?

Comment: I'd like to unique the whole dataset. Can I ask one more question-- is DT slower when I use dplyr verbs? I'm a big fan of the work that went into making the package super efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `pattern` argument to match the substring 'filename', followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by `_`, four digits ('year') and the `.csv` at the end (`$`) of the string

```
all.files <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "^filename\\d+_\\d{4}\\.csv$")

l <- lapply(all.files, fread, sep=",")
dt <- rbindlist(l )
setkey(dt, ID)
unique(dt, by = 'ID')
```